# Disign Actionbar or create something like it

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create an ActionBar like in the picture or to create something like it.

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B6Cz2zvfARSdOHJKSEppSzd6ZHM&usp=sharing

Comment: This isn't a question. What would you like help with?

Comment: how to make  the bar in the top of the picture (drawerbutton,"mes cercles",picture_pen)? by customizing the action bar or i make it manually?

Comment: any idea please, i am amateur in android and iineed help with this

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the [style of your ActionBar](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html).

See tutorial on [adding buttons](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html).

If you want to support pre-Honeycomb versions of the OS, you will need to start by using the [ActionBar compat library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html).